What is this part of the freezer that is cracked? And what to do about it?
I have an Ikea fridge / freezer and I've just started to defrost the freezer and as the ice has melted away I've noticed these cracks - what are they and what should I do about them?
I presume it's time for a new fridge / freezer but should I keep the freezer off until then, should I keep defrosting or close it and call replacement immediately?
I'm anxious about continuing to defrost / clean it if this is potentially dangerous...


Defrost that thing!

in the process of doing so!

it's a molding to hold a plastic bracket that holds the evaporator coil in place. The bracket is missing (but present on the coil below). The nubbin to hold the bracket got mangled as the drawer bumped into the bracket because it was just thin plastic with only a prayer and a dream that the expanding foam insulation got into that nook and cranny.
Behind that is the aforementioned insulation.
It's fine really, it won't affect the performance of the freezer. The exposed insulation might be a place for mold/pathogens to grow if it wasn't freezing cold there constantly. You can use some plastic wrap to seal it off if you are paranoid.
